# Dice Roll app not working on IPhone, is it due to transform?

Tags: reactjs

I am experimenting with a dice roll game, I have searched and modified a dice roll app code, and the die is working perfectly with Android but when I roll the dice on iPhone the dice vanish, its like transform is not supported or negative angles are not supported
I don't have Safari unable to debug the issue!
but that would be interesting why the dice roll vanished
Any help would be appreciated

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

const Die = ({ dieRef, onFaceChange }) => {
    const faces = 6;

    const [intrvl, setIntrvl] = useState();
    const [diceFace, setDiceFace] = useState(1);
    const [btnDisabled, setBtnDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [rollTimes, setRollTimes] = useState();

    function rollDice() {
        setBtnDisabled(true);
        clearInterval(intrvl);
        let counter = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 4 + 1)) + 4;
        setRollTimes(counter);
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const newFace = Math.floor(Math.random() * faces) + 1;
            setDiceFace(newFace);
            onFaceChange(newFace);
            counter--;
            if (counter === 0) {
                clearInterval(interval); // Stop rolling after 4 to 5 times
                setBtnDisabled(false);
            }
            setRollTimes(counter);
        }, 200);
        setIntrvl(interval);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (rollTimes === 0) {
            clearInterval(intrvl);
            setBtnDisabled(false);
        }
        dieRef.current = rollDice;
    });

    const dice = (
        <div className="dice-container">
            <div className={`dice face-${diceFace}`}>
                <div className="face-1">
                    <div className="dot-container">
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="face-3">
                    <div className="dot-container">
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="face-4">
                    <div className="dot-container">
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="face-2">
                    <div className="dot-container">
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="face-5">
                    <div className="dot-container">
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="face-6">
                    <div className="dot-container">
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                        <div className="dot"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div
            className="main-dice-container"
            onClick={() => (btnDisabled ? null : rollDice())}
        >
            {dice}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Die;
```

```
.main-container {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-dice-container {
    padding: 25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.dice-container {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    perspective: 500px;
}

.dice {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-origin-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 200ms;
}

.dice.face-1 {
    transform: rotateX(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(0);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.dice.face-2 {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateY(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(90deg);
}

.dice.face-3 {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.dice.face-4 {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg);
}

.dice.face-5 {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateY(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}

.dice.face-6 {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

.dot-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
    grid-gap: 2px;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.dot {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.dice [class^='face'] {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 6%;
    outline-offset: -2px;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.dice .face-1 {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(40px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(40px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(40px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.dice .face-2 {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.dice .face-3 {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.dice .face-4 {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.dice .face-5 {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.dice .face-6 {
    transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(40px);
    -webkit-transform-origin: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(40px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(40px);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.button-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.dan-btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dan-btn[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.dan-btn--default {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    color: #444;
}
```